# Default C# universal app throw Class not registered

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

Just like many of you yesterday I updated my workstation with windows 8.1 Update 1. I also installed vs2013 with the RC update to begin developing Universal Windows Apps. However when i run the apps on my W8.1 machine with the update I get the exception shown below:

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))   at
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start(ApplicationInitializationCallback
>   callback)    at App1.Program.Main(String[] args)

Please note that this app is created using File -> New Project -> Universal App template. No custom code was added to it.

WHen googling this error I found that in the previous version of windows jou had to download the Media Feature Pack however the versions offered on the microsoft site are not compatible anymore on my updated machine. Has anyone else seen these problems and know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The cause for my problem was that my Avast Antivirus was scanning my app that I ran from visual studio. After disabling the filescanner for my project dir my apps launched perfectly.